# Firebase init hosing:github for organization

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, github-actions

Trying to create a github action connection to firebase, as described  [here](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-firebase-hosting) .

After initializing hosting, I ran:

`firebase init hosting:github`

Got to the stage where got:

> For which GitHub repository would you like to set up a GitHub workflow?

Entered the name, and then received:

`Error: HTTP Error: 403, Policy update access denied.`

The repo is part of an organization.

Read those threads:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3143
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2763

about giving fire base access to the organization, but I already have given access[image: access granted to firebase].

Any suggestions how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the problem was that I needed to be an **Owner** (Editor isn't enough) of the fire base project in order to initialize the Firebase hosting.